# Creating a PsychoPy rating task

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm new to PsychoPy but I would like to create a 'rating task' where participants are shown 20 images from a folder (called Folder1) and along the bottom are 4 different categories of rating ('A lot', 'A little bit', 'Not very much', and 'Not at all').

I would like participants to be shown the 20 images from the folder one at a time and then click on one of the four boxes to categorise that image before moving onto the next image.

Does anyone know if this would be possible on builder view alone or whether I would need to add in some Python code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be possible to design purely in the graphical Builder environment. This does make this not really a programming question *per se* then, which is what StackOverflow is really for.

I'd suggest you start with the Stroop task tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VV6qhuQgsiI. This will teach you the basics of controlling and randomising stimuli from a conditions file. From there, further questions are probably best addressed to the support forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org, which is better suited than StackOverflow to these non-programming, Psychopy-specific, questions.